# Choosing polar projection and tiling scheme for web mapping of polar regions?

Tags: coordinate-system, web-mapping, antarctica, arctic

I am looking for examples of web maps focusing on polar regions (Arctic or Antarctic) preferably using a polar projection.

What polar projection and tiling scheme could be used for such web mapping applications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- NASA's [Operation IceBridge](http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/icebridge/index.html) has a web map for its [data portal](http://nsidc.org/icebridge/portal/) hosted by [NSIDC](http://nsidc.org/) (National Snow & Ice Data Center). It has tabs to switch between northern and southern hemispheres.
- This might not be a good example as it is pretty static and it's in Flash, but National Geographic has an interactive map here: [Discover Antarctica](http://ngm.nationalgeographic.com/ngm/antarctica/)
- Sometimes all you need is a PDF: [Antarctica Ice Velocity map](http://eoimages.gsfc.nasa.gov/images/imagerecords/51000/51781/antarctica_ice_velocity_lrg.pdf) ([info](http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/IOTD/view.php?id=51781))

Answer (score 1):

The [European Atlas of the Seas](http://ec.europa.eu/maritimeaffairs/atlas/maritime_atlas/#lang=EN;p=a;pos=1.802:-0.747:4;bkgd=100995:1;gra=0;mode=1;theme=100306:0.5:1:0,100156:0.25:1:1,100304:1:1:0,100302:1:1:0,100305:1:1:0;) is another great example of geoportal centered on the arctic.