# QGIS crashes when changing projection to South Pole Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, lambert-conformal-conic

I can change the projection to every projection I have tried successfully except for South Pole Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area. When I click `apply` the loading bar appears in the bottom of QGIS and says 'loading tiles' it does this for several minutes before finally crashing. I went ahead and upgraded to the most recent version of QGIS to see if that fixed it and it did not.

Does anyone have experience with a similar problem or know what might be going wrong?

Comment: Do you have any layer loaded in the project?

Comment: Just an OSM or ESRI base map

Comment: Neither of those base maps will reproject to a polar projection.

Comment: Are there any options for basemaps that will?

Comment: Basemaps are usually web served as Web Mercator projections, wich validity range doesn't include the poles. I don't know if there are a public web service of basemaps in other projection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the answer that came out in the comments above...

The basemaps you're using (OSM and ESRI base maps) are not compatible with a polar projection. Like most basemaps, these are served in the Web Pseudo-Mercator projection (EPSG:3857). That projection doesn't extend to the poles. The valid extent of that projection is: `-180.00, -85.06, 180.00, 85.06`, which means it covers the entire 360 degrees along the east-west axis, but it only extends as far north as 85.06 degrees, and as far south as -85.06 degrees.

You need a special south pole basemap. Fortunately, these exist. Unfortunately, they don't seem to exist inside the Quick Map Services plugin, so you will have to learn to load a WMS layer through the Data Source Manager, which can be quite tricky. [Here's](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/online_resources/wms.html) a tutorial. The basemaps that come with the QMS plugin are loaded in XYZ tile format, so if you find a basemap in tiled format you can look at the settings of one of the QMS basemaps you already loaded, and use them as a template to help you get the settings correct on the other layer. See [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/276815/81764) for detailed steps.

With a quick google search for "wms antarctic basemap" I found the following basemaps:

- https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/d13b9d10219e4429974e48368b64e41f
- https://gis.ngdc.noaa.gov/arcgis/rest/services/antarctic/antarctic_basemap/MapServer

WMS stands for "web mapping service," which is a format that many basemaps come in. They also come as REST services and XYZ tiles, so you might find different resources using those search terms.

I also found a few questions here on GIS StackExchange about polar basemaps that have some really promising-looking answers.

- [Choosing polar projection and tiling scheme for web mapping of polar regions?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76244/choosing-polar-projection-and-tiling-scheme-for-web-mapping-of-polar-regions)
- [Tiled Web Map; what tile provider offer antarctic map tiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/249728/tiled-web-map-what-tile-provider-offer-antarctic-map-tiles)

Answer (score 1):

Type `world` to the coordinates field at the bottom of the QGIS window: it will load a vector shapefile showing countries. Change the project CRS at the very bottom right of the QGIS window to `ESRI:102020` to show the basemap in South Pole Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area projection:
[image]

For me, using QGIS 3.20 on Win10, it even works with an OpenStreetMap basemap:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with base maps. QGIS does not work well with the South Pole Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area projection, regardless of the basemap used. I hope they solve it because you cannot work on projects with the Antarctic area as a study area, for example.

Comment: Do you have any information that substantiates your statement that QGIS does not work well with South Pole Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area projection? In what context, what workflow, what data etc.?